# JAXBElement<String> to String using Simple Framework for Android

Tags: android

I'm having big time trouble with Android Webservice.

I am converting JAXB Annotation to Simple Annotation. Please see below.

Here is my JAXB Annotation:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Title", namespace = "http://xxx.org/2004/07/Course", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> title;
```

I get the value using getTitle().value();

After mapping to Simple Annotation like this:

```
@Element(name = "Title",  required = false)
    protected String title;
```

and getTitle() returns null. how can i get the value ?

I cannot use JAXB on Android. So how could I properly use Simple Framework to get the value?

I badly need help on this. Thank you so much.